# NullPointerException thrown when unit-testing a Play controller's action that processes a form

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework-2.5

I encounter `NullPointerException` when testing an action that processes a form. There are two actions, one to display and one to process the form. Testing the first one is fine; however, testing the second one throws the exception. This only happens with unit-testing; the application works fine (i.e., via browser). I can't figure out what happens. Could anyone help me shed some light on it? The code I'm testing is as follows.

- Scala: 2.11.8
- SBT: 0.13.11
- Play Framework: 2.5.2

**build.sbt**

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "1.10.19" % Test,
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.1" % Test
)
```

**project/plugins.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.2")
```

**conf/routes**

```
GET     /           controllers.FormController.showForm
POST    /           controllers.FormController.processForm
```

**app/controllers/FormController.scala**

```scala
package controllers

import javax.inject.Inject

import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms._
import play.api.i18n.{I18nSupport, MessagesApi}
import play.api.mvc._

case class UserData(name: String, email: String)

class FormController @Inject()(val messagesApi: MessagesApi) extends
  Controller with
  I18nSupport {

  def showForm = Action {
    Ok(views.html.showForm(getForm))
  }

  def processForm = Action { implicit request =>
    getForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      errForm => Ok(views.html.showForm(errForm)),
      userData => Ok(userData.toString)
    )
  }

  val getForm: Form[UserData] = Form(mapping(
    "name" -> nonEmptyText,
    "email" -> email
  )(UserData.apply)(UserData.unapply))
}
```

**views/main.scala.html**

```
@(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  @content
</body>
</html>
```

**views/showForm.scala.html**

```
@import helper._

@(myForm: Form[UserData])(implicit messages: Messages)

@main {
  <h3>Form</h3>
  @form(action = routes.FormController.processForm()) {
    @inputText(myForm("name"))
    @inputText(myForm("email"))
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  }
}
```

**test/controllers/FormControllerSpec.scala**

```scala
package controllers

import org.scalatest.mock.MockitoSugar
import org.scalatestplus.play.PlaySpec
import play.api.i18n.MessagesApi
import play.api.test.Helpers._
import play.api.test._

class FormControllerSpec extends PlaySpec with MockitoSugar {
  "FormController" when {
    "showForm" should {
      "display the form" in {
        val cut = new FormController(mock[MessagesApi])
        val response = cut.showForm(FakeRequest())
        status(response) mustBe OK
      }
    }

    "processForm" should {
      "redisplay the form in case of form errors" in {
        val cut = new FormController(mock[MessagesApi])
        val req = FakeRequest(POST, routes.FormController.processForm.path)
        val response = cut.processForm(req)
        status(response) mustBe OK
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output from running test:

```
[info] FormControllerSpec:
[info] FormController
[info]   when showForm
[info]   - should display the form
[info]   when processForm
[info]   - should redisplay the form in case of form errors *** FAILED ***
[info]     java.lang.NullPointerException:
[info]     at views.html.helper.FieldElements$$anonfun$errors$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Helpers.scala:35)
[info]     at views.html.helper.FieldElements$$anonfun$errors$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Helpers.scala:35)
[info]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
[info]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
[info]     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
[info]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
[info]     at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
[info]     at views.html.helper.FieldElements$$anonfun$errors$2.apply(Helpers.scala:35)
[info]     at views.html.helper.FieldElements$$anonfun$errors$2.apply(Helpers.scala:31)
[info]     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
[info]     ...
[info] ScalaTest
```

Comment: your post request is most likely invalid

Answer (score 0):

In the example you posted you haven't trained your mock. As a result when you try to render the template it's trying to call `apply` on the mock and it's going to throw. For reference, `MessagesApi`:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/i18n/Messages.scala#L320

Properly training this mock would be very difficult. Instead what you can do is build an instance of `DefaultMessagesApi` and provide that to be wired into your controller:

```
val config = Configuration(ConfigFactory.load("application.conf")) // Or test.conf, if you have test-specific config files
val messages = new DefaultMessagesApi(Environment.simple(), config, new DefaultLangs(config))
val controller = wire[MyController]
```